# Generic Insert Statement in SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a table in SQLite consisting of cars and options for each car.

```
Name     Option
----     ------
Mini     Sunroof
Mini     Stereo
Chevy    Heater
```

I need to insert a new option for all car models, but without using separate insertions for each model. So, for instance, adding the option "AC" (without writing statements for each car) would result in:

```
Name     Option
----     ------
Mini     Sunroof
Mini     Stereo
Chevy    Heater
Mini     AC
Chevy    AC
```

I have heard that `insert into` can use a query, but I have no idea how to do so. What is the syntax for using queries in inserts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query would look like this:

```
insert into Cars (Name, Option)
select distinct Name, 'AC'
from Cars
```

I do not know how you communicate with your `SQLite` db so you have to pass option parameter somehow.